# Getting error while importing numpy on python shell on windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, python-requests

I got this exception:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\...\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\...\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\...\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\...\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\...\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.
```

Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: sorry @Xukrao, i'm trying to install OpenCV, but the requirements are to install firstly: Python then Numpy.

Comment: But i'm getting an error when: i write this on the Python shell: "import numpy"...

Comment: line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\SHABAZZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>

Comment: Have you installed NumPy? (The most usual way for all data science packages in Python is [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/what-is-anaconda/)), expecially on Windows. Translate the error message to English. Fix the typo in title and capitalize product names there correctly

Comment: @hynekcer ok i will test it with Anaconda